# Can I see the command given to the compiler to build a project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if it is possible to see the command given to the compiler to build a project in Visual Studio 2012. How can I achieve that?

(I'm interesed in .Net C# projects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go and change it to `TOOLS -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project output verbosity -> Normal`

Then you'll see what you want in the `Output` window.

Example output:

`CoreCompile:
1>  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation ...`

Comment: I was looking for that option.

Comment: Glad it helped. I use it to troubleshoot build problems sometimes, very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see the `CSC.exe` command used by Visual Studio.

Comment: This tool is amazing but I can't find any trace of csc.exe when I build some project. The closest thing I see is MSBuild.exe (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe  /nologo /nodemode:1 /nr). Maybe csc.exe isn't used at all?

Comment: Yeah it is amazing - its built by Mark Russinovich. Here is the trick. It captures HDD, Reg, Process info in REAL-TIME. So you need to start it and really quickly reproduce the problem/build and then quickly stop the trace. Because it logs so much info I usually export the results via csv into Excel and do the Auto Sort - to filter out non-Viusal Studio activity and then search for `csc.exe`

Comment: Thanks for the brief tutorial. I figured out how to use it before writing my previous comment. I think that csc.exe isn't used by Visual Studio acording to Process Monitor.

Comment: @DanielSan csc.exe is spawned by the MSBuild process, not directly by devenv.exe

Comment: @JeremyThompson You should really look into the filtering function of procmon (ctrl+L). Setup filters for the processes and operations you care about, THEN start capturing data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but are you looking for this  [command line building](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx)

Comment: I want to know what is happening under the hood when I press "build"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Output tab at :
    Menu -> Debug -> Windows -> Output

Comment: I only see messages like:`'ConsoleApplication8.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded '....dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.` I want to know how the command given to the compiler to build the project.