# How can I see the C#.NET compile command with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I've found some other reference, but it's old:

[10 year old thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486080/can-i-see-the-command-given-to-the-compiler-to-build-a-project)

It says:

```
Go and change it to TOOLS -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project output verbosity -> Normal

Then you'll see what you want in the Output window.

Example output:

CoreCompile:
1>  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation ...
```

I can't see that this is working now. I've tried to clean the solution and look for csc in the output window.

Is this supposed to work now?;)

Comment: Show us what you actually see in the Build Output window.

Comment: The normal verbosity shows csc.exe in VS 2022 on my side. Did you look in the correct output window? In the Output window, select "Build" in the "Show output from" list.

Comment: Works for me if I set "MSBuild project build output verbosity" to "Detailed" rather than "Normal". The answer you're referring to is talking about an older style (.NET Framework era) project, for which the logging may be different to the newer SDK-style project build.

Comment: Thank you. I set it to "detailed" and now I see it;) If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.